# Is there any Elliptic Curve algorithm equivalent to RSA's asymmetric encryption?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I've been searching but I cant find anything about this... only [EC Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) with symmetric cryptography, which is exactly what I do not want :(

Imagine this:

- generate a random private key, `k`
- then calculate a "public key" with ECC, `d=kG`

The algorithm I'm looking for is this: any message cyphered with the public key will "only" be decyphered by the owner of the private key.

Does this exists? Has anything like this been developed yet?

Comment: Have you looked at [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography)?

Comment: yes... I havent found solution yet

Comment: I'm a little confused. Did you look at the section on [ECDSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA) which is a public key algorithm based on ECC?

Comment: yes i have... In section "Key and signature size comparison to DSA" its written: "Suppose Alice wants to send a signed message to Bob.". Also in "Signature verification algorithm" step 2 has: "e=HASH(m)" That m is the plain text message. This means that ECDSA is only used to check the message integrity. As far as the algorithm is concerned, the trasnmission can be: "plain_text_message+signature"... :(